# Не правильно выглядит grid расстановка

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Вот фото.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выглядит не очень. Это пока что набросок кода. В дальнейшем я хочу открыть elf файл. Обозначить подсветкой секции и elf заголовок. Например заголовок elf будет около красным. Другие секции другими цветами. По этому виду будет понятно где код, где данные. Получение значения секций и кода я уже сделал в консольной программе. Осталось сделать в qt. Может быть сделаю в ncurses, если в qt не получиться.

Вот код.

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    mlayout = new QGridLayout;

    menubar = new QMenuBar(this);
    pmenu = new QMenu("Program");
    pmenu->addAction("Open File", this, SLOT(open_file()));



    menubar->addMenu(pmenu);

    mlayout->setMenuBar(menubar);

    this->setLayout(mlayout);


    frame = new QFrame[22];
    for ( int i = 0; i < 22; i++ ) {
        frame[i].setParent(this);
        frame[i].setFrameStyle(QFrame::Sunken);
    }

    line = new QLineEdit[22];
    for ( int i = 0; i < 22; i++ ) {
        line[i].setParent(&frame[i]);
        line[i].setFixedWidth(20);
    }

    mlayout->setHorizontalSpacing(1);
    mlayout->setVerticalSpacing(1);


    for ( int i = 1, x = 0, y = 0, index = 0; i < 23; i++, index++, x++ ) {
        if ( i % 16 == 0 ) {
            y++;
            x = 0;
        }
        mlayout->addWidget(&frame[index], y, x );

        frame[index].show();
        line[index].setText("00");
        line[index].show();

    }

}

Widget::~Widget()
{

}

void Widget::open_file()
{
    path_file = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName( 0, "Select program", "", "*" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте главный виджет производным от QMainWindow, меню у него можете редактировать в  дизайнере, затем установите в него свой виджет, примерно так:

```
Widget *w = new Widget;
mainWindow->setCentralWidget(w);
```

Comment: Это что поможет избежать того вида, который щас видно на снимке?

Comment: Если бы вы написали, что вам не нравится в виде, то может быть вам помогли его избежать

Comment: Я хочу сделать hex редактор. Ячейки должны быть близко друг к другу, а они на большом расстоянии. И ничего не помогает изменить эту ситуацию. Ещё я QLineEdit засовываю в QFrame, и frame делаю выпуклым, но это не отображается.

Comment: Надо поджать с краю пружинкой: QSpacerItem

Comment: Но, возможно вам лучше подойдёт таблица - QTableWidget. Есть ещё QTableView, но это наверное слишком сложно пока для вас